# Get refresh token with Auth0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, auth0

I am developing an API. I implemented register, login, and Facebook auth using Auth0.

My token expires after one day, and I need to get my refresh token to sign in the user again without requiring its credentials again. I have to make a call to `/authorize` with these parametrs [sic]:

```
GET https://YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN/authorize?
audience=API_IDENTIFIER&
scope=SCOPE&
response_type=code&
client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&
redirect_uri=https://YOUR_APP/callback&
state=STATE
```

but I get this error [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqpB9.png)

The `GET` response should give me a code, which I would use to get my refresh token making another GET request on `/oauth/token` like that: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKw9E.png)

Does anyone have any idea how to get over the first step?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using curl to get access token and refresh token and then refresh outside of your app? The following link has very detailed instruction on how to do that with auth0.

https://auth0.com/learn/refresh-tokens/